# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Project' not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am developing web based project management tool using laravel 5. when I execute it occurred following error.

> FatalErrorException in ProjectController.php line 37: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\Project' not found

Comment: which namespace you have on ProjectController.php  ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import your **Project** class with proper **use** statement, otherwise PHP will look for this class in current namespace.

E.g. if your **Project** class is in **App\Models** namespace, add the following at the top of your controller file:

```
use App\Models\Project;
```